# How would I sort Java objects in which the object's compareTo method logically shouldn't be consistent with the equals method?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, comparable, treeset

I have the following class:

```
public class EventPriority {
    Event myEvent;
    Double priority;
}
```

This class logically encapsulates an event and it's priority. I'm writing a framework which will take **n** number of these events as input and it will trigger the top **k** events out of the total **n**; I only want to top **k** events with highest priority.

I was thinking of achieving this by having the EventPriority class implement **Comparable** like so:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(EventPriority other) {
    return other.priority.compareTo(priority);
}
```

and using a **BoundedTreeSet** that has a max size of **k**. If inserting an item causes the size of the set to go beyond the max size, it removes the last element from the set.

However, two objects of the EventPriority class are logically the same if they have the same event. So:

```
Event myCommonEvent = new Event();
EventPriority firstPriority = new EventPriority(myCommonEvent, 0.9);
EventPriority secondPriority = new EventPriority(myCommonEvent, 0.1);
```

In this case, **firstPriority** is logically the same as **secondPriority**, but they just have different values of priority.

From all that I've read online, it's not a good idea to have the **compareTo()** method inconsistent with the **equals()** method.

So what can I do in this case?

Comment: Implement a custom `Comparator` and use it where appropriate.

Comment: But the inconsistency still remains, right? Irrespective of whether I use a custom comparator or implement Comparable, they won't be consistent with the equals method.

Comment: Sure, but it is not part of `EventPriority`. If you need custom comparison logic, you need custom comparison logic, there's no way around that. The best you can do is to extract it to some other component so as not to confuse the type itself.

Comment: Why not add it as the answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a getter for `priority`, `Comparator.comparing()` makes creating a custom comparator simple:

```
Comparator<EventPriority> comparator = Comparator.comparing(EventPriority::getPriority);
```

Comment: Hmm.. Sadly, I haven't yet upgraded to Java 8.